# Q about AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType() and getBean()

Tags: java, spring

We have the following legacy 2.0.7 Spring code:

```
final Map<String, MyClass> secondaryFactories
     = (Map<String, MyClass>) context.getBeansOfType(MyClass.class, 
                                                     false, true);

return (MyClass) context.getBean("myClass");
```

where `context` is an instance of

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
```

Note that we ignore the return value of `getBeansOfType()`.  This works just fine, but the problem is that the call to `getBeansOfType()` is time-consuming.  However, even though we ignore the return value of this call, if we try to eliminate this call, then the instance of `MyClass` returned by `getBean()` is not fully initialized.  (So, apparently, the call to `getBeansOfType()` is having some sort of side-effects that we need.)

We suspect that the call to `getBeansOfType()` is overkill and we could do something more lightweight so that the instance of `MyClass` obtained by the call to `getBean()` would be fully initialized (but it's not null and no exception is thrown).

So, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What is BeanType.MY_CLASS.getName() ?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest turning on logging and seeing what goes on. Spring is usually quite helpful.

Second of all, one difference between `context.getBeansOfType` and `context.getBean` is that `getBeansOfType` does not query the parent context. If you have one, you might hit a difference here.

Third of all, I assume the 'driver' bean is lazily initialised. Do you have any sort of multi-threaded code running while the context is initialized? There have been [reports](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-4672) of fixes late in the 2.5 cycle related to that. `getBeansOfType` might be just generating a delay or hitting a memory barrier so that the issue with `getBean` returning an uninitialised bean is hidden.

Fourth of all, you might want to - just for argument's sake - try running the application with Spring 2.5.6. If it works, you know the guilty party.

Comment: +1 for enabling debug-level logging, spring's very verbose at that level